# Finding the limit of a function $\frac{x}{x^{2n}+1}$

Tags: limits

$$
f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}⁡\frac{x}{x^{2n}+1}
$$

Domain of f(x) is $\Bbb R$.Find the value of $f(1^+ )$
I am not able to understand how to solve it. Please help me.

Comment: It will help a great deal if you were to try to write the math instead using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  Instructions on how to do so [can be found here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It sounds like you are asked to find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2n}+1}$.  You then make a reference to some $f$ which hasn't been mentioned yet.  What is this $f$?  Are you perhaps asking for $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^+} \left[ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{x^{2n}+1}\right]$?

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x}{x^{2n}+1}$$? The copy and paste did not work i guess.

Comment: No JMoravitz sir. Thank you for your comment.I have done some edits.Please verify it

Comment: yeah Chinny84 sir.  The copy and paste did not work.

Comment: What is the domain of definition of $f$?

Comment: @AlexM., the points where the limit exists.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Ahh, my mistake: what is the domain of $\frac x {x^{2n} + 1}$? Is it considered defined on the whole $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @AlexM., yes. $2n$ is even, so $x^{2n}+1>0$.

Comment: Domain is R sorry I didn't mention in the question Alex sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given domain of definition of $f_n = \frac x {x^{2n} + 1}$ is $\Bbb R$. Note that if $x \in (-1, 1)$, then $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} x^{2n} \to 0$, so $f_n(x) \to x$. If $x = \pm 1$, then $x^{2n} = 1$, so $f_n(x) = \frac x 2$. Finally, if $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$, then $x^{2n} \to \infty$, so $f_n (x) \to \frac x \infty = 0$. To summarize:

$$f (x) = \left\{ \begin{eqnarray}
0, & x<-1 \\
-\frac 1 2, & x = -1 \\
x, & -1 < x < 1 \\
\frac 1 2, & x = 1 \\
0, & x > 1
\end{eqnarray} \right. .$$

This shows that

$$f(1^+) = \lim \limits _{x \to 1, x > 1} f(x) = \lim \limits _{x \to 1, x > 1} 0 = 0 .$$

Comment: @saisaandeep: How intelligent to unaccept an answer 6 months after having accepted it, only to accept an answer with fewer details! Bravo!

Answer (score 2):

$$x>1 \implies\lim_{n\to\infty}⁡\frac{x}{x^{2n}+1} = 0\implies
\lim_{x\to 1^+}\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x}{x^{2n}+1} = 0.$$